# JQuery mobile form loses formatting after first view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page in JQuery mobile, which contains a form.  The form has both static elements (defined in the html) and dynamic elements (created through script at runtime).  The first time I go to my page, it renders correctly, with the JQuery mobile formatting.  If I go back, then open the form again, all formatting of **dynamic elements** is lost.  I have to reload the page to get my elements looking correct again.

My suspicion is that the DOM is being messed up somehow.  I'm calling empty() on the parent element holding the dymanic content, so there shouldn't be duplicate elements in the DOM.

Have reproduced this on both Chrome (windows) and the Andriod 2.3 browser.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm doing.  In the real application, the elements come from a database, so most form views may contain different elements.  Hence, they need to be re-created each time.

To see the behavior,

1. click the "Show form" link,
2. click the back button,
3. then click the "Show form" link again.  You will notice the formatting is gone.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tj4yF/1/

**Code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <meta content=" initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;user-scalable=0;" />
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                    var g_aElementList = [];
                        g_aElementList.push( "<label for='ta'>General comment</label><textarea name='ta' id='ta' rows='3'></textarea>" );
                        g_aElementList.push( "<label for='num'>My Number</label><input type='number' name='num' id='num'/>");
                        g_aElementList.push( "<label for='chk'>My Checkbox</label><input type='checkbox' name='chk' id='chk' value='true'/>");

                    $("#pnlPage2").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event, ui) {

                        var jContainer = $("#elementContainer");

                        for( var cI=0; cI<g_aElementList.length; cI++ ) {
                            jContainer.append( "<li data-role='fieldcontain'>" + g_aElementList[cI] + "</li>" );    
                        }

                        jContainer.page();


                    });

                    $("#pnlPage2").live("pagehide", function(event, ui) {
                        $("#elementContainer").empty();
                    });

                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="pnlPage1">
                <div data-role="header"> 
                  <h1>Page1</h1> 
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <a id="pnlTest" class="panel" href="#pnlPage2">Show form</a>
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer"> 
               </div>
            </div>
             <div data-role="page" id="pnlPage2">
                <div data-role="header"> 
                  <h1>Page2</h1> 
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <form id="frmTest">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                            <div id="elementContainer"></div>
                        </ul>   
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer"> 
               </div>
            </div> 

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going wrong. But I do feel that perhaps deleting and adding new dom elements is not really nescesairy. Also you may place everything in the document.ready wrapper to prevent errors.

Somehow there's a problem with #elementContainer being emptied. A workaround is do dynamically create it and afterwards delete it.

**Edit: Now it should be working without the hide/show**

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kkyWg/1/

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var g_aElementList = [];
    g_aElementList.push( "<label for='ta'>General comment</label><textarea name='ta' id='ta' rows='3'></textarea>" );
    g_aElementList.push( "<label for='num'>My Number</label><input type='number' name='num' id='num'/>");
    g_aElementList.push( "<label for='chk'>My Checkbox</label><input type='checkbox' name='chk' id='chk' value='true'/>");



    $("#pnlPage2").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event, ui) {
        $('<div id="elementContainer"></div>').appendTo("#list");

        var jContainer = $("#elementContainer");
        for( var cI=0; cI<g_aElementList.length; cI++ ) {
            jContainer.append( "<li data-role='fieldcontain'>" + g_aElementList[cI] + "</li>" );
        }
        jContainer.page();

    });

    $("#pnlPage2").live("pagehide", function(event, ui) {
        $("#elementContainer").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  In the real application, the elements come from a database, so most form views may contain different elements.  Hence, they need to be re-created each time.

Comment: Regarding the doc.ready, I have done that in the application, just trying for the most basic example to demonstrate my problem here.  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Great.  That solved it.  Though I'd be interested to know why.  The only difference is that instead of removing the contents of the container, we are now removing and re-creating the container itself.

Comment: Whatever it is, is has to do with the page() method I think.