# Jquery Mobile list has no formatting

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a dynamic list from data that is retrieved from a MYSQL databas on my 2nd page within my site and for some reason all the data that I am generating and putting into an HTML 'li' isn't taking on any jquery mobile effects. I am using the new beta 1 version. Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

---

```
//move to second page from intial post
var newpage = function(){

    $.mobile.changePage('#page2');  

}


$("#page2").live("pagebeforeshow",function(){

//dynamically creating the div tag to hold all <li> elements
    $('<div id = "listHolder"></div>').appendTo("#here");

    var restaurant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('restaurant'));
    var dataString2 = 'restaurant=' + restaurant;                                               

    //php call to get data from the database
    $.post("getResults.php", dataString2, callback);                                                            


});

//remove the div tag when the page disappears
$("#page2").live("pagehide", function(event, ui) {
        $("#listHolder").remove();
    });


//function to call from the php request
var callback = function(json){

    var dataList = JSON.parse(json);

    var list = "";

    //building the list
    for (x = 0; x < dataList.length; x++){
        list += "<li>" + dataList[x].PartySize + "<span class='ui-li-aside'>" + dataList[x].Quote + "</span></li>";
    }


    document.getElementById('listHolder').innerHTML = list;
    document.getElementById('restaurant').innerHTML = dataList[0].Restaurant;
}                   



<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <center><h2><div id="restaurant"></div></h2></center>

    </div>
    <div data-role='content'>

        <ul data-role='listview' id = "here" data-inset='true' data-theme='c'><li data-role='list-divider'>Party<span class='ui-li-aside'>Mintues til Sat</span></li>


        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: fixed the formatting a bit... some crazy tabs going on, but at least now we can see it a bit better.

Comment: @Patricia: Thanks, though I was hoping to train user812578 into doing it his- or her-self

Comment: *blush* oops.  i got impatient hehe

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to debug if you show us a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I got it fixed. Thanks Jasper

Comment: @user812578 - if you have it fixed, why don't you accept the answer from @Jasper

Answer (score 1):

Try calling .listview() on the ul element after the new li tags are inserted.

```
$('#here').listview(); //at the end of your append'ing
```

Also could you just .append() each li tag onto the ul instead of dynamically adding the intermediary div tag?

Comment: Tried both suggestions with no luck.

Comment: I do this on my website, so I know it can be done, my method is to either load the whole UL object into the dom (into a div container) or load individual LI objects into a UL already on the page ($('#here').append('<li>text here</li>')). After loading the information I call .listview() on the UL object and presto, I get a styled list.

Comment: Also I have seen .listview('refresh') in other people's code, perhaps this is for a list element that has already been rendered, I have not tested its use though.

Comment: I got it fixed, I originally had the whole ul tag and everything in there but wasn't using .listview() after. I switched my code back the way you suggested and it works now. Thank you very much

Comment: Jasper, do you know the call to fix the same issue with textboxes on a page?

Comment: With jquery mobile alpha 4.1 I used the .page() function after dynamically adding buttons or form elements, however I have not found this to work with the beta 1.0.

Comment: If you find an alternative in beta 1 please post it here and inform me. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#here').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.page()`

Maybe here:

```
document.getElementById('restaurant').innerHTML = dataList[0].Restaurant;
$("#page2").page();
```

Comment: this breaks the button from the first page and won't even load the 2nd page

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like your setting the inner html of a `<div>` to a bunch of  `<li>` elements,   which is likely to cause some problems!  they need to be inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.  you shouldn't have a `<div>` inside a `<ul>`!

if you want to replace everything in the li, i would take out the

```
$('<div id = "listHolder"></div>').appendTo("#here");
```

and change:  `document.getElementById('listHolder').innerHTML = list;`  to `document.getElementById('here').innerHtml(list);`

if you just want to add the html in `list` to the bottom of the list do this:

```
`$('#here').append($(list));`
```

instead of

`document.getElementById('listHolder').innerHTML = list;`

Comment: I've tried previously to just adding the whole ul tags and their content to the list variable and then putting that inside of a div and it didn't work.

Comment: you don't need the div at alL!

Comment: I tried the dynamic div based of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246837/jquery-mobile-form-loses-formatting-after-first-view